# Create html select based on datetime mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, date

So, I have this table with data similar to what is shown:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id(int) +   stamp(datetime)   + initials(text) + rating(decimal[4,2]) +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+         +                     +                +                      +
+ 1       + 2016-12-21 12:23:01 +  STA           + 1.07                 +
+ 2       + 2016-11-17 16:15:19 +  CKO           + 8.22                 +
+ 3       + 2016-08-06 12:33:00 +  VER           + 4.58                 +
+ 4       + 2016-08-14 19:54:34 +  FLO           + 2.43                 +
+ 5       + 2016-12-11 01:09:22 +  WIS           + 9.16                 +
+ 6       + 2016-09-28 05:43:51 +  WIN           + 5.53                 +
+ ...     + ...                 + ...            + ...                  +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I would like to create a select using a month/year combo, like:

```
<select name="display">
  <option value="08-16">08-16</option>
  <option value="09-16">09-16</option>
  <option value="11-16">11-16</option>
  <option value="12-16">12-16</option>
</select>
```

and in the backend

```
<?php
$myoptions = "<select name=\"display\">\n";
$myquery = "SELECT QUERY HERE";
$myresult = mysqli_query($mysqli, $myquery) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
while($myrow(mysqli_fetch_array($myresult)) {
  $thedateandtime = explode(" ", $myrow['stamp']);
  $dateparts = explode("-", $thedateandtime[0]);
  $year = $dateparts[0];
  $month = $dateparts[1];
  $myoptions .= "<option value=\"".$month."-".$year."\">".$month."-".$year."</option>\n";
}
$myoptions .= "</select>\n";
echo $myoptions;
?>
```

I didn't want to end up with multiple month/year combos, like having two December and two August in the select options. Thoughts?

Comment: One option would be to use a calendar table in MySQL to generate the month-year choices.

Comment: something that is off-topic but thought I should mention it in case you are new to PHP etc... at this point in time it makes much more sense to use PDO instead of the mysqli DB connection due to security issues.

Comment: I'm not too worried about the security as the script will be sitting on a machine that will not have access to or be accessible from the internet.

Comment: fair enough but staff are the cause of many hacks.

Comment: While I appreciate everyone's concern for the safety aspect, I can reassure you that the only person that would have access to this machine would be my wife and daughter. It's a home machine and I am using it for personal data analysis. I could hard code the month-day, but I would rather have the interface as dynamic as possible. Thanks. :)

Comment: Just wait for your wife and daughter to become hackers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so my newb (to StackOverflow) self found the answer, so here it is in case anyone else runs into the problem:

```
$myoptions = "<select name=\"display\">\n";
$myquery = "SELECT CONCAT( MONTH(`stamp`), '-', CONCAT( YEAR(`stamp`) ) ) as `mystamp` FROM `entries` GROUP BY YEAR(`stamp`), MONTH(`stamp`)";
$myresult = mysqli_query($mysqli, $myquery) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
while($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($myresult)) {
$myoptions .= "<option value=\"".$myrow['mystamp']."\">".$myrow['mystamp']."</option>\n";
}
$myoptions .= "</select>\n";
echo $myoptions;
```

This was possible due to the fact that the "stamp" column was a datetime field.